# Get substring of argv[0] between n and the length of argv

Tags: c, string, substring

I'm trying to get a substring of `argv[0]` and output it to another string. I've already got the positions I want, I just can't figure out how to do it from other answers. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#include "echo.h"
#include "whoami.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // applet_length: Length of first arg filename excluding things like "./"
    int applet_length = sizeof(argv[0]);
    // real_length: Full length of first argument
    int real_length = 0;
    while ((argv[0])[real_length])
        real_length++;
    int start = real_length - applet_length;
}
```

`start` is the point I want to start the substring from, and `real_length` is the overall length of `argv[0]`. How would I go about doing this?

I'm doing this for the purposes of making a coreutils executable like BusyBox where you can run an applet by invoking a symlink with its name.

E.g. `argv[0]` is `"test1234"`, start is `4`, real_length is `8`, output is `"1234"`

---

I ended up with:

```
#include "echo.h"
#include "whoami.h"
// etc.
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *applet = basename(argv[0]);
    if (!strcmp(applet, "echo"))
        echo(argc, argv);
    else if (!strcmp(applet, "whoami"))
        whoami(argc, argv);
    // etc.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with `argv`. You are trying and failing to get the length of a nul terminated string. Search for "length of string".

Comment: sizeof(argv[0]); isn't the same as strlen(argv[0])

Comment: Why do you want to skip the first `sizeof(char *)` bytes of `argv[0]`?

Comment: since `argv[0]` is a pointer to an array of char, `sizeof(argv[0])` actually gives you the size of a pointer (which is likely not what you want). `strlen(argv[0])` would get you the length of the string (not including the nul terminating character)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: OP seems to know about that, but is somehow interested in the difference between the two (that is, `(int)strlen(argv[0]) - (int)sizeof(char *)`) for reasons not explained here (I can't think of any).

Comment: @mafso : Agreed can't quite tell what the intent of the code was. I figured I'd explain the whole sizeof() thing because I don't see how that seems to factor in.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `strlen()`?  Also, I'm not sure how any of this code (even if `sizeof(argv[0])` did what you might have thought it did) would give you the length of a string excluding things like `"./"`.  And how would this do anything like what you describe in your last line, other than by the coincidence that `sizeof(argv[0])` - which is the size of a pointer - might be the same as the number of characters in "test"?

Comment: My executable filename was 4 characters and applet_length was 4 so I thought that sizeof must give the size of the real file name...

Comment: ... but I tried it with a different filename and was still 4

Comment: Use `size_t applet_length = strlen(argv[0]) + 1;` to get the count of `char` including the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: `sizeof()` only can tell you the sizeof a type, it doesn't know anything about the types themselves (whether they hold string numbers, gorillas or monkeys). `sizeof` will simply return the number of bytes used to hold any given data type.

Comment: `char substrng[strlen(argv[0])-n+1]; strcpy(substring, &argv[0][n]);`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I can easily check argv[0] against another string and run that program but I need to get it somehow to "simplify" the filename, otherwise it won't recognise things like "/bin/program" as "program"

Comment: @MichaelPetch is there a better way of doing this? can I get the filename of the running program?

Comment: @DevilishDB, POSIX has a `basename()` function that you might already have.

Comment: If you are on Linux then I recommend you look at something like `basename()` : http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname . For example if you do this `printf ("%s", basename(argv[0]))` it will print out the file name with the path removed. Just include <libgen.h> if you are using a POSIX compliant compiler. It won't work on Windows VC++ for example.

Comment: @MichaelPetch updated Q to show what I did

Comment: Glad you got it going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program with comments explaining how you can do what you want.  Hopefully it will help you learn how to solve such problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Use if strdup() is unavailable.  Caller must free the memory returned. */
char *dup_str(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *r;
    if ((r = malloc(n)) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(r, s);
    return r;
}

/* Use if POSIX basename() is unavailable */
char *base_name(char *s)
{
    char *start;

    /* Find the last '/', and move past it if there is one.  Otherwise return
       a copy of the whole string. */
    /* strrchr() finds the last place where the given character is in a given
       string.  Returns NULL if not found. */
    if ((start = strrchr(s, '/')) == NULL) {
        start = s;
    } else {
        ++start;
    }
    /* If you don't want to do anything interesting with the returned value,
       i.e., if you just want to print it for example, you can just return
       'start' here (and then you don't need dup_str(), or to free
       the result). */
    return dup_str(start);
}

/* test */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *b = base_name(argv[0]);

    if (b) {
        printf("%s\n", b);
    }
    /* Don't free if you removed dup_str() call above */
    free(b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your base name assumes the path separator is `/`. Some non-POSIX environments like Windows would use `\\` . I'd probably opt for Boost.

Comment: Yes, the function is not portable.  Also it doesn't do some error-checking (apparently `argc` can be 0 and then `argv[0]` can be `NULL` etc).  Boost is not an option in C.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm on Linux and yup, it's C not CPP